# Вычисление кратности в цикле

Tags: python-3.x, циклы

Не могу понять, в чем разница между работающим:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
i = 1
while i % a != 0 or i % b != 0:
    i += 1
print(i)
```

и уходящем в бесконечный цикл:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
i = 2
while a % i != 0 or b % i != 0:
    i += 1
print(i)
```

По логике оба цикла должны привести у одному результату и на этом закончиться...

Comment: Лучше вместо `int(input())` написали бы конкретные значения :)

Comment: Допустим, a = 5, b = 3.

Comment: "По логике оба цикла должны привести у одному результату" - по логике такого как раз не должно произойти.

Comment: Я уже понял. Бессонная ночь просто дает свои плоды.

Answer (score 1):

В первом примере у Вас находится остаток от деления переменной i на переменные a и b:

```
while i % a != 0 or i % b != 0:
```

Во втором же примере Вы пытаетесь найти остаток от деления переменных a и b на переменную i:

```
while a % i != 0 or b % i != 0:
```

Условие в цикле постоянно выполняется, поэтому он становится бесконечным

Answer (score 0):

Выспался и с ужасом понял, на сколько невнимательность губительна. Как сказал один хороший человек:"Лучший дебаг - это здоровый сон".
Если у кого подобный случай - вот ответ: деление переменной `i` на вводные работает всегда, деление вводной на `i` - только при условии `a == b`